# How do I move user folders for many users to a new server?

Tags: windows, user-management, files

I need to move two users folders on two separate drives on a main DC to another shared folder on a NAS. These user folders are the users main home drives.

What is the best way to do this without doing it one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [**xcopy**](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true) or [**robocopy**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(WS.10).aspx) from the Microsoft Windows Resource Kit (and optional [GUI](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.11.utilityspotlight.aspx)) to do the copying of data.

Answer (score 1):

[Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) is your friend.

Comment: Robocopy does not work. I need to move all the user home folders to a NAS. I cant run Robocopy from there. Unless I can run robocopy from a remote server, moving the user files from the DC to the new NAS. Is this possible? Can I move these home folders and save their rights with robocopy to the NAS?

Comment: You can specify UNC paths in the Robocopy arguments, thus you can use it anywhere to copy from A to B, so long as they are both accessible to you.

Comment: You can preserve ntfs permissions using the /COPYALL switch.  Have you tried using Robocopy?  Why are you saying it does not work?  You don't have to run robocopy from the NAS, you can run it from the DC.

Comment: You are correct. robycopy is getting done what I need it to do. The issue I have now is that the permissions do not carry over to the NAS. I am trying to figure out how to get the user folders that were moved with robocopy from the DC to the NAS to be accessible to the users once I change their home drive mapping. Once I changed the home drive mapping in AD it worked (as in it mapped the users folder on the NAS) but not the user folder for that user, just the users folder that contains all the user folders and the account has access to read all the folders in there. Which cant happen.

Comment: its a linksys/ cisco NAS and has only limited interface for security settings, it only allows 21 people to be assigned to one share for some reason. So I am trying to work out how to not have to set up separate shares for each user account. I want to do it in a mass change. It looks like I am still going to have to do each one individually, unless I can find a way to make a mass change in rights for each new user share on the NAS.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I found the solution to my issue. The NAS cannot do what I thought it could. It is a NSS6000 Linksys and it seems that the limitations in the security rights interface is hindering the rights I need to be able to set.

So I am going to order a new file server that will be the primary user home drive server and set this server up as a member server in our domain.

Thanks for all your help. I did not know that robocopy has a new version called RichCopy, and it has a really cool interface GUI.

Thanks all.